# memory leak in php if array has more than 1024 items

Tags: php, memory-leaks

Why i have memory leak? For $numIterations < 1024 all fine

```
echo "[0]Mem usage is: ", memory_get_usage(), "\n";

$arr = array();
$numIterations = 1024;

for ($i = 1; $i < $numIterations; ++$i) {
    $std = new stdClass();
    $std->random = rand(0, 10000000);
    $arr[$i] = $std;
}
echo "[1]Mem usage is: ", memory_get_usage(), "\n";
unset($std);
unset($arr);
echo "[2]Mem usage is: ", memory_get_usage(), "\n";
```

Comment: it literally says, you do not have enough memory. I can exceed the 1024 iterations, because i have more memory. It is your hardware - and you will keep having the problem, if you are not unset'ing it in-between or upgrading your ram.

Comment: seems that it may be related on creating the new stdClass many times in less memory. Are you trying to store random vaule?

Comment: If you are hitting your memory limit in PHP you can look at increasing the value for [`memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).